# How to pairwise compare values referring to distinct elements in two matrices of different formats?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a set of objects, let's say with the IDs 'A' to 'J'. And I've got two data frames which look the following way (as you can see, the second data frame is symmetric):

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:5], Var = c(9,13,15,11,28))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(NA,42,83,74,84,42,NA,26,69,9,83,26,NA,67,95,74,69,67,NA,6,84,9,95,6,NA), ncol = 5, nrow = 5, dimnames = list(df1$ID, df1$ID)))
```

For example, take the objects 'B' and 'E'. I want to know: Is 13+28 (from `df1`) less than 9 (from `df2`)? I'd like to know this for all pairs of objects. The output should be

(a) a logical data frame structured like `df2` and

(b) the number of "TRUE" values.

Most of the time I will only need result (b), but sometimes I would also need (a). So if (b) can be calculated without (a) and if this would be significantly faster, then I'd like to have both algorithms in order to select the suitable one dependent on which output I need to answer a particular question.

I'm comparing around 2000 objects, so the algorithm should be reasonably fast. So far I've been only able to implement this with two nested `for`-loops which is awfully slow. I bet there is a much nicer way to do this, maybe exploiting vectorisation.

This is what it currently looks like:

```
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, ncol = nrow(df1), nrow = nrow(df1),
                            dimnames = list(df1$ID, df1$ID)))

for (i in 2:nrow(df3)){
  for (j in 1:(i-1)){
    sum.val <- df1[df1$ID == rownames(df3)[i], "Var"] + df1[df1$ID == names(df3)[j], "Var"]
    df3[i,j] <- sum.val <= df2[i,j]
  }
}
```

#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
df3 <- outer(df1$Var, df1$Var, "+")
df3

df4 <- df3 < df2
df4

sum(df4, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Perfect and amazingly short! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it...

```
#  Get row and column indices
ind <- t( combn( df1$ID , 2 ) )

#  Get totals
tot <- with( df1 , Var[ match( ind[,1] , ID ) ] + Var[ match( ind[,2] , ID ) ] )

#  Make df2 a matrix
m <- as.matrix( df2 )

#  Total number of values is simply
sum( m[ ind ] > tot )
#[1] 7

#  Find which values in upper triangle part of the matrix exceed those from df1 (1 = TRUE)
m[upper.tri(m)] <- m[ ind ] > tot
#   A  B  C  D  E
#A NA  1  1  1  0
#B 42 NA  1  0  1
#C 83 26 NA  1  1
#D 74 69 67 NA  0
#E 84  9 95  6 NA
```

Comment: Thanks! While testing your solution on my original data, I realised that one tricky part is that calculations on matrices seem to be much faster than those on data frames. I'll keep this in mind for the future!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

```
# Generate the data
df1 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:5], Var = c(9,13,15,11,28))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(NA,42,83,74,84,42,NA,26,
                                     69,9,83,26,NA,67,95,74,69,
                                     67,NA,6,84,9,95,6,NA),
                            ncol = 5, nrow = 5,
                            dimnames = list(df1$ID, df1$ID)))

# Define a pairwise comparison index matrix using 'combn'
idx <- combn(nrow(df1), 2)

# Create a results matrix
res <- matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(df2), nrow = nrow(df2))

# Loop through 'idx' for each possible comparison (without repeats)
for(i in 1:ncol(idx)){
  logiTest <- (df1$Var[idx[1,i]] + df1$Var[idx[2,i]]) < df2[idx[1,i], idx[2,i]]
  res[idx[1,i], idx[2, i]] <- logiTest
  res[idx[2,i], idx[1, i]] <- logiTest
}

# Count the number of 'true' comparisons
nTrues <- sum(res, na.rm = TRUE)/2
```

The code simply uses a pairwise comparison index (idx) to define which elements in both df1 and df2 are to be used in each iteration of the 'for loop'. It then uses this same index to define where in the 'res' matrix the answer to the logical test is to be written.

N.B. This code will break down if the order of elements in df1 and df2 are not the same. In such cases, it would be appropriate to use the actual letters to define which values to compare.